# module RFID-RC522 MySQL, Python

Tags: raspbian, python, rfid

I have the following problem. I am working with Python and RaspberryPi 3 recently.

My task is to write the data (RFID together with date and time into the MySQL database).

Date and time works, they are displayed in MySQL.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal
import time
import MySQLdb

global c
global db

continue_reading = True


def insert_to_db():
    rfnummer = (getrfnummer())
    zeit = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    datum = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print((RFnummer + " - " + zeit + " - " + datum))
    sql = "INSERT INTO TAB_RFID (RFnummer, T_Date, T_Time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    try:
        c.execute(sql,(str(rfnummer), str(datum), str(zeit)))
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
    # db.close()


def read_from_db():
    try:
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM TAB_RFID ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result is not None:
            print(('RFnummer: ', result[0][1], '| time: ', result[0][3], ' | datum: ', result[0][2]))
    except:
        print("read error")

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal, frame):
    global continue_reading
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

## Hook the SIGINT

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

## Create an object of the class MFRC522

MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

## This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID and authenticate

while continue_reading:

```
# Scan for cards
(status, TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

# If a card is found
# if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
# print "Card Detected"

# Get the UID of the card
(status, uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

# If we have the UID, continue
if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:

    # Print UID
    # print str(uid[0])+str(uid[1])+str(uid[2])+str(uid[3])

    time.sleep(0.5)

    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
        print((time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

def main():
    while 1:
        insert_to_db()
        read_from_db()
        # time.sleep(5)

if **name** == '**main**':
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "mydb")
        c = db.cursor()
    except:
        print("Keine Verbindung zum Server...")

```
try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("bye bye...")
    pass
```

Comment: I've got some code you can have at https://github.com/DougieLawson/BSK_Hackathon that reads RFID tags and stores the data in MySQL.

Comment: module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'MFRC522' :(

Comment: Go and get it from GitHub.

Comment: Sorry but i dont now how :(

Comment: https://github.com/paguz/RPi-RFID  this dont work

Comment: install its work